# Python requests-html with Tor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

The requirement is to scrap anonymously or change ip after certain number of calls. I use the https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html module to parse the HTML, but i get the below error,

```
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

Code

```
import socks
import socket
import requests_html

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr='127.0.0.1', port=int('9150'))
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://icanhazip.com')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
print(r.html.text)
```

But it works perfectly fine with requests module,

```
import socks
import socket
import requests

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr='127.0.0.1', port=int('9150'))
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

print(requests.get("http://icanhazip.com").text)
```

Any help to solve the issue with requests-html module would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `requests-html` appears to not use socket to load the page but rather appears to use a chromium instance from which it fetches the HTML once the JS on the page has completed perhaps you need to configure that to use your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
session = requests_html.HTMLSession(browser_args=["--no-sandbox","--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9150"])
```

Depends on how your proxy is set up to use tor but this worked for me!